# Fetch meta-tags from url only by jQuery

Tags: url, dom, jquery, meta-tags

Now a lot of scripts to facebook-style fetching data from url, but all of them work only in combination of jQuery and PHP. Is it possible to fetch url only by jQuery?

I have found here how to get mata-tags of page by:

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
$("meta[property=og:title]").attr("content", document.title);
```

But how correctly insert this query in jQuery.get() to get text values?

```
$.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/', function(data) {
  $('meta[name=adescription]').attr("content");
});
```

And if the most popular sites use OpenGraph should I look in the direction of jQuery.getJSON()?

Comment: Won't the request have the problem of cross-domain origin ?

Comment: Try this tool ,Buzzstream is product. http://tools.buzzstream.com/metaDataService?url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the html data retrieved from URL

```
$.get('http://www.guardian.co.uk/culture/2012/jun/21/jimmy-carr-apologises-error-tax', 
function(data) {
   $(data).find('meta[name=adescription]').attr("content");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns me the whole page, and doesn't fide meta-tags in it

Answer (score 18):

It seems like this wouldn't be possible because of the [Cross Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/same-origin-policy-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing)

There are definitely ways of doing it with combination client & server side changes. Instead I've been using this API in a project that works well as a simple REST API to get a url's open graph data. 
`GET https://opengraph.io/api/1.0/site/<URL encoded site URL>`
https://opengraph.io/

It's been working for me as a client-side javascript only solution.

[NOTE: I have no relationship to this product or its creators. I found it through online research and used it in a project.]

Comment: I just updated the post to explain - no relationship, just a user.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

With filter works fine!

You can try.

```
$.get('http://www.guardian.co.uk/culture/2012/jun/21/jimmy-carr-apologises-error-tax', function(data) {
    $(data).filter('meta[name=adescription]').attr("content");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible using [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere):

```
$.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/", function(data) {
    var meta = $(data).filter('meta[name="apple-itunes-app"]').attr("content");
    console.log(meta)
});
```

Used `apple-itunes-app` because it's an actual meta tag on IMDB.