# CORS - What does it protect?

Tags: http, cors

I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and I wonder what or who that should protect. If you start Chrome for example in a mode without security restrictions it calls all the APIs on the other domain without preflight and whatsoever. This means a naughty guy can get around this very easily. I don't see how this should protect the owner of a server application, the owner of such an application can have an authentication to protect its site. So what is the scenario who gets protected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [same-origin policy and CORS - what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167428/same-origin-policy-and-cors-whats-the-point)

Answer (score 0):

If a script in `example.com` sends a request to `somebank.com` and the user is logged in to `somebank.com` it can retrieve the financial information of the user. Since the script is under the control of `example.com` it can then transmit that information back to its owner.

This of course begs the question why forbid the request altogether instead of making a request without session id's/cookies. This can be done server-side anyway.

Comment: You gave a scenario that can go bad without CORS, but haven't really explained how CORS prevents this from happening.