# Giving CORS issue while using ionic-image-loader plugin on Android device and Browser

Tags: angular, cors, ionic3, image-loading

I had used ionic image loader plugin, Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader

When I try to load an image using "img-loader" as below

```
<img-loader src="https://path.to/my/image.jpg" useImg></img-loader>
```

It gives CORS issue for accessing an image path.

Displaying the following issue!

> Failed to load https://path.to/my/image.jpg: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**while whole other images in normal "img" tags works and loads fine.**

Even Apis works fine from localhost origin because 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is set to '*' on the server end.

But at the time of using ionic image loader, image URL doesn't pass access control check in its preflight request.

Comment: _“Even Apis works fine from localhost origin because 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is set to '*' on the server end”_ - what “server end”? Are you talking about the server behind the `path.to` “domain” here, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about server behind path.to domain

Comment: And for which request methods? (A preflight request is OPTIONS.)

Comment: Normal Apis preflight request pass the access check, But when I use Ionic image loader than image-URL makes a request with method 'options'(Preflight) and gets a CORS issue.

Comment: Well then you have to fix your server-side setup, so that it properly responds to a preflight request for an image as well ...

Comment: Yes! but what exactly needs to be done on server-side to allow images?
That's I'm searching right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What webserver are you using? For Apache, you can find an approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42558499/1427878

Comment: Im using apache, Thanks!