# React development: Adding headers property in fetch raises CORS error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors

The following error is from the *Network* section of firefox:

[image]

I've tried solving the above error by adding a `headers` (based on various answers from similar problems) property in the native `fetch`  function when sending a React API request (or a native ES6 request for that matter).

```
fetch('API_ENDPOINT', // API_ENDPOINT is a different sub-domain
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization' : 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
).then(...);
```

Removing the `headers` section allows the request to go through (I have validated this by returning a custom message in the response `header`) but I need this to add the *Authorization* header because I authenticate the request via the Basic token (I will migrate to Bearer soon but the same approach will be used). It looks like the initial set of headers are being replaced once I've added the `headers` property?

Note: I have an `.htaccess` that allows cross-origin request with definition:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT,GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

SOLVED:

This has been solved by implementing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42558499/335547

- The `credentials` should be included as `fetch` property so the *Authorization* header will be considered in the preflight validation.
- The API should use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ***with*** specific source host, ***not*** `"*"`
- The API should use of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I known, when you defined `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"` you cant specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`, you have to define `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a specific list of urls