# Loading of `$metadata` fails due service from https://services.odata.org not supporting CORS

Tags: odata, sapui5, ui5-tooling, sap-business-application-studio, sap-business-technology-platform

I am trying to consume Northwind R/W OData service link: `https://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/`.

It is working fine on local testing. But without using proxy or mock server, the service reports the following error:

> NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented

Controller code:

```js
// ODataModel required from "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
var oModel = new ODataModel({
  serviceUrl: "https://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/",
  headers: {
    DataServiceVersion: "3.0",
    MaxDataServiceVersion: "3.0"
  }
});
```

Comment: Please avoid the current accepted answer. `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` is no longer usable as announced in https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using Northwind, I believe it's **only for development**. So you can make use of `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to access cross origin resources.

```js
var oModel = new ODataModel({ // required from "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
  serviceUrl: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://services.odata.org/V2/(S(frik5l2zde0sxh4jiifyhqo4))/OData/OData.svc/"
});
```

Or the other way would be to <del>disable security flag in chrome for development</del> make use of [destination settings within SCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878337/5846045).

Answer (score 3):

**Update (2021-06-16):** for the OData V4 [*TripPin*](https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/) service, a reverse proxy server is no longer required as the host [now supports CORS](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues/29).

---

**Original answer:**

The problem is that [services from *odata.org* currently don't support CORS](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues/29). To learn about what CORS is in general, see [Same origin Policy and CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14681292/5846045).

In short, this is what happens in your case:

1. Client sends a preflight request, with the method `OPTIONS`, to see what kind of requests are allowed by the server.
2. Server responds that it doesn't understand that `OPTIONS` request.
3. Client reports "OPTIONS ... 501 (Not Implemented)".

One of the options to circumvent this issue is to use a reverse proxy server which can be configured in *SAP Business Technology Platform* (aka. SAP BTP, formerly known as SAP Cloud Platform or SCP) as well as by using *UI5 Tooling* in case of local development.

There is an extensive documentation about how to solve this. Please go through the topic [Request Fails Due to Same-Origin Policy (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e) and apply the changes according to your development environment.

If working with UI5 tooling locally, I recommend [`ui5-middleware-simpleproxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui5-middleware-simpleproxy).

---

<del>The public proxy service `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` may seem to work at first, but it preliminarily sends every single request with a preflight request sequentially (i.e. two requests every time) since preflight requests are **not** cached by that server by default.<sup>[src](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/blob/4814647a9d21f14858da282387a4295c17f2851d/lib/cors-anywhere.js#L256)</sup> Also the number of requests per period is limited there, so **you will get blocked** when sending several requests too many times.</del> → **UPDATE:** `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` is officially no longer usable. See the announcement: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301