# Bootstrapping SAPUI5 App Locally Throws Error after Upgrading UI5 Resources to 1.54

Tags: google-chrome, sapui5, local, development-environment

The local SAPUI5 applications do not work with 1.54.xxx anymore. They work fine with 1.52.xxx.

By "local SAPUI5 applications" I mean applications:

- loaded from local drive without http server
- using CDN
- using browser with disabled SOP like
  Chrome with *--disable-web-security --user-data-dir*

Such application work fine with 1.52.xxx:

```
src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.52.11/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
```

but dumps with error from ui5loader-dbg.js with 1.54.xxx:

```
src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.4/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
```

The errors occurs during loading of Components.js or controllers, samples from two programms:

> ui5loader-dbg.js:882 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'zprog/Component.js' from ./Component.js
>   ui5loader-dbg.js:882 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'ztest2/controller/App.controller.js' from ./controller/App.controller.js: 0 -

Do you know the reason of it and have an idea how to run local SAPUI5 application with 1.54?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main cause is the browser not supporting asynchronous XHRs for local files (`file://`) as [mentioned in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server#The_problem_with_testing_local_files):

> Some browsers (including Chrome) will not run async requests (see [Fetching data from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data)) if you just run the example from a local file. This is because of security restrictions (for more on web security, read [Website security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Website_security)).

As UI5 gradually moves towards asynchronicity ([#UI5Evo](https://youtu.be/vZfxBXu6_Lc)) and due to the security reasons, developing applications with the **`file://` protocol should be avoided.**

Instead, try to **setup a local HTTP server** for which many tools are out there, such as [**Web Server for Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb). Running the app on the server also allows the browser to respect [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14681292/5846045) (No need to turn *web-security* off).

---

### Discouraged Approach

Despite the [framework not supporting the `file://`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2020#issuecomment-386514228) protocol, relying on [unsupported and buggy command-line flag](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690), ignoring security standards, and being uncertain about whether the **workaround** might still work in the future or not, you can still make the app run with the version 1.54 if all requests are made asynchronous. For example:

> - Given:
>   - Chrome's command line flag
>     - `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`
>     - Or `--allow-file-access-from-files`
>   - [UI5 sample application](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2020#issuecomment-386236493) provided on the equivalent GitHub issue
> - Before loading the `sap-ui-core.js` file, activate the hidden experimental flag `xx-async`.
>   ```html
>   <script>
>     window["sap-ui-config"] = {
>       "xx-async": true
>     }
>   </script>
>   ```
> - And load everything else asynchronously as usual, such as providing `async: true` when creating [ComponentContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer/controlProperties) or [root view](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/e7f69cca0c5e638f4cae32f3be05368036b46868/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/walkthrough/09/webapp/Component.js#L14).
>   [image: Workaround working]

---

## Update (2018/05/10)

Just yesterday, there was a [new commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/b451ba7171c982f46f455149dce189688cea0eb4) that shed more light on why it didn't work after upgrading to 1.54 and why the workaround above had to make use of async XHRs everywhere.

With 1.54, a [new internal file *ui5loader.js*](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ffc711b09f1a409acc87729f7cf373bc0123c64c) was introduced. Besides many cool features it brought, it also took mostly the code from *jquery.sap.global.js* away that handled loading modules. While migrating, a fallback to sync XHR had to be implemented for the case when legacy sync APIs are used. That was realized with the [function `loadSyncXHR`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.54.1/src/sap.ui.core/src/ui5loader.js#L1022-L1052).

In that `loadSyncXHR` function, the module was considered *loaded* when the returning XHR status was `200`. However, as the new commit suggests, some browsers, including Chrome, return the status `0` when the file was loaded from a `file://` protocol. That check was missing until yesterday, so it had to be added.

> `if ( xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0)`

If you run the same project with `src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/..."` without changing the code, the errors shouldn't be thrown anymore.

Comment: As I wrote the 1.52 version works ok (also with Chrome and file:// ), the problem occurs after switch to new version 1.54. The local http server would be a new heavy and very disappointing dependency.

Comment: @AnnieW. I just updated my answer above. If you make everything asynchronous, it still works with 1.54. But again, working with `file://` protocol is definitely not encouraged when developing UI5 applications. I have a hard time understanding why setting a local HTTP server implies "heavy dependency" for you. With the [*Web Server for Chrome*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) for example, only a few clicks are required to set it up.

Comment: @AnnieW. The issue is now fixed and I updated my answer accordingly. It's still recommended to use HTTP server (either `localhost` or some other hosts such as via Web IDE)