# Make Curl request using axios

Tags: javascript, curl

I was going through the facebook docs and their they have used curl for making api calls

```
curl -G \
-d "fields=name" \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads"
```

I have heard previously about the curl but never used it before

Now, I am big on axios, and I am thinking that this would be similar to restful api calls.

So to get the data from the given above snippet, I would need to m**ake a get request since in the above snippet it says?**

```
curl -G \
```

Secondly the given url is

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads"
```

So axios equivalent would be

```
axios.get("https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads")
```

and then **`-d` i am guessing is for data**? so my api request should look something like this?

```
axios.get("https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads"
  ,data: {
     fields: "something",
      access_token:"8e8e8ee08e0e"  
    }
)
```

Can someone confirm that what I am doing is correct or not?

Comment: Are you wanting to run the JavaScript in a browser or via Node?

Comment: @Phil via browser but is there a difference when making request via axios from node or javascript.

Comment: Cross-domain requests come with their own set of challenges. See [Same origin Policy and CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/same-origin-policy-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there...

Typically, using the `-d` option in `curl` forces a POST request with the `-d` values encoded into the request body. Setting the `-G` option forces a GET request with those data parameters encoded into the URL query parameters.

> `-G`, `--get`
>   When  used, this option will make all data specified with `-d`, `--data`, `--data-binary` or `--data-urlencode` to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

Axios separates query parameters into the `params` object, so you should use that instead of `data`.

```js
axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${apiVersion}/act_${adAccountId}/ads`, {
  params: {
    fields: "something",
    access_token:"8e8e8ee08e0e"  
  }
})
```

Comment: @phill what does -f stands for? -F 'name=My Ad Set'? this is from following facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api

Comment: @anny123 not sure what you mean, that doesn't appear anywhere in my answer. If you're asking about the general use of `curl`, there's plenty of documentation available ~ https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F