# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status - React issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the Dwolla API and have already made the activated HTTPS for the local host. I'm still getting a CORS issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlmI0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's `CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing` error.

[Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

[Beautifully answer in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/same-origin-policy-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing?rq=1)

Can you specify which library are you using to make request. If it's axios then you can try following which is using proxy -

```js
axios.get('https://a.4cdn.org/a/threads.json', {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    proxy: {
      host: '104.236.174.88',
      port: 3128
    }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('response is : ' + response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.headers);
        } 
        else if (error.request) {
          console.log(error.request);
        } 
        else {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

Hope this helps you.