# Not able to use OData V2 (Northwind) data in SAPUI5 App

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, ui5-tooling

I am trying to use Northwind data service (OData V2) in my SAPUI5 app. However, I am not able to get any data at all from the server.

This is my XML view:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="c.g.odataapp2.controller.Root"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
    <Table id="idOrdersTable" items="{odm1>/results}">
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <Text text="OrderId" />
        </Column>
        <!-- ... -->
      </columns>
      <ColumnListItem>
        <Text text="{odm1>OrderID}" />
        <!-- ... -->
      </ColumnListItem>
    </Table>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

This is controller code:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
], function (Controller, ODataModel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("c.g.odataapp2.controller.Root", {
    onInit: function () {
      var oModel = new ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$format=json");
      this.getView().setModel(oModel, "odm1");
    }
  });
});
```

Do I need to set up anything else (Not mentioned in the docs)?
I have used proxy/https/...link.... but this seems to be not working as either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly two issues in the question:

1. **Application code**

   - Invalid service URL: when passing a string to the `ODataModel` constructor, the string needs to be pointing to the resource where the OData service serves the service `$metadata` document. Therefore, **`Orders?$format=json` needs to be removed** from the string.
   - Replace `items="{odm1>/results}` with `items="{odm1>/Orders}` in the view definition.
2. **Issue with CORS ***

   The public demo proxy server `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` is no longer directly usable without having a temporary access requested first (See the related [announcement](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301)).

   Instead, continue with the "Resolution" section from the documentation topic ["Request Fails Due to Same-Origin Policy (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS)"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e). Expand the subsection corresponding to your development environment.

   In case you're working locally without setting a destination in SAP BTP:

   - Expand and follow the subsection "Local Development: Configure a local proxy"
   - Or make use of the [`ui5-middleware-simpleproxy`](https://github.com/ui5-community/ui5-ecosystem-showcase/tree/main/packages/ui5-middleware-simpleproxy). Here is a sample `ui5.yaml` config with the middleware: https://github.com/boghyon/gitpod-ui5-basic/blob/main/ui5.yaml. Keep in mind to execute `npm install ui5-middleware-simpleproxy --save-dev` in your terminal beforehand. To configure the `ui5-middleware-simpleproxy` in `ui5.yaml` for consuming the Northwind service from `odata.org`, you could set:

     1. `mountPath: /myODataService`
     2. `configuration/baseUri: https://services.odata.org`
     3. And finally in your controller code:

        ```js
        new ODataModel("/myODataService/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc"); // without .../Orders?$format=json
        ```

   ***** With the exception of the [OData V4 TripPin service](https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService), services from `odata.org` currently don't support CORS. To learn about CORS in general, see [Same origin Policy and CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14681292/5846045).

   If the service doesn't support CORS, the service might report a vague report, **for example:**

   1. Client sends a preflight request with the method `OPTIONS` to see what kind of requests are allowed by the server.
   2. Server responds that it doesn't understand that `OPTIONS` request.
   3. Client reports `"OPTIONS ... 501 (Not Implemented)"`.

---

### TL;DR

In general, **OData services from `odata.org` are poorly maintained, incomplete, and has many issues** some of which I already reported at https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3Aboghyon.

Services from `odata.org` don't support generating CSRF tokens either. Add `tokenHandling: false` when defining the constructor settings for the `v2.ODataModel` class:

```js
new ODataModel({ // V2
  serviceUrl: "/myMountOrDestinationPath/...",
  preliminaryContext: true,
  defaultBindingMode: "TwoWay",
  tokenHandling: false, // prevents "HEAD ... 501 (Not Implemented)" from odata.org services
  // ...
})
```

Instead of referring to services from `odata.org`, take a look at this blog post for alternative sample **OData services maintained by SAP:** [**"New SAP Gateway Demo System available"**](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/05/new-sap-gateway-demo-system-available/).

Comment: Hi, have used this link = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", this solves the cors error, but still its showing error 404 (metadata not found). I have also setup ui5-middleware-proxy and still its not working. Last resort is to use BTP destination. Is there any other way to do this ? thank you.

Comment: @SAPASFlash "proxy/https/..." doesn't really solve anything. It's just a random string in that case. I just enhanced my answer above with how you could use the `ui5-middleware-simpleproxy`. Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. But when creating the SAPUI5 project using the application generator in VSCODE, there is an option for connecting to an OData System. So the Northwind SVC link can be provided there and the generator should take care of the rest of the problem by configuring all the required files? or we still have to manually configure the yaml file?

Comment: @SAPASFlash You'd still have to configure the connection to the service since the generator wouldn't know if the OData service is CORS-enabled or not. Would be an interesting feature request, though, for the generator. Which generator are you referring to exactly? Maybe I could create an issue in the respective GitHub repo if possible.

Comment: I am referring to the Fiori Application Generator available for VSCODE. After a bit of hurdle, I found out that creating a BTP Destination for Northwind OData on BTP Cockpit and then using that system when creating the UI5 project solves the cors problems, but I am yet to try that out by myself.

Comment: @SAPASFlash Yes, creating the destination in BTP is one of the solutions as outlined in the mentioned topic  ["Request Fails Due to Same-Origin Policy (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS)"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e) (click on the section "SAP Business Application Studio: Configure a destination").

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the proxy-service "herokuapp.com" is not working anymore.
Try to remove the part from your URL. This will result in a CORS-error.
To fix this follow the suggestions from the documentation
[Request Fails Due to Same-Origin Policy (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e.html)