# Get Meta Description from URL using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to get the meta description of the parent page from an iframe, what i did uptill now is that i get the url of the parent page, pass that url to jquery and try to get the meta description but it doesn't work, my code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addToInterest() {
        var URL = parent.window.location;
        var Title = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
        var MetaDescription = "";
        var Img_Src = "";
        var metaDesc = $.get('http://myURL.com', function (data) {
            MetaDescription = $(data).find('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
            Img_Src = $(data).find('link[rel=image_src]').attr("href");
        });
        alert(MetaDescription);
        alert(Img_Src);
    }
</script>
```

But in both alerts, it shows nothing.. i have already tried the methods told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136011/fetch-meta-tags-from-url-only-by-jquery)

but did not successfull.
any sample code please....

Regards:
Mudassir

Answer (score -1):

`$.get` is asynchronous. Both your `alert`s executed just after `$.get` call, but at this moment HTTP request can be still in progress. You need to move your `alert`s inside of callback function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addToInterest() {
        var URL = parent.window.location;
        var Title = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
        var MetaDescription = "";
        var Img_Src = "";
        var metaDesc = $.get('http://myURL.com', function (data) {
            MetaDescription = $(data).find('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
            Img_Src = $(data).find('link[rel=image_src]').attr("href");
            alert(MetaDescription);
            alert(Img_Src);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Also note, what your code will hit Same Origin Policy. By default you can't dynamically load resources, placed on other host, than you script.

Comment: Then you trying this way, does alerts appear at all (event with `undefined`)?

Comment: I have tried both ways you told, but didn't work either way.. if i place the alerts inside the function, it simply doesn't get executed.. and outside the function, it alerts but shows nothing in the message...

Comment: I think you hit Same Origin Policy. Check your browser's console for erros and also check Network tab in firebug/Chrome devtools. I think your request to myURL.com is not even executed.

Comment: Olegas ! by viewing the javascript console, i found the follwoing error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myURL.com. Origin http://localhost:45950 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. how to manage it..??

Comment: Google about Same Origin Policy and Cross Origin Resource Sharing