# How to fetch meta tags from external URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, meta-tags

I have seen that this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136011/fetch-meta-tags-from-url-only-by-jquery) the but the solution no longer works. I have tried myself in this [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/92899c26632df90ed860a14882709523?editors=101).

This is the error that I get : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://vimeo.com/114166139. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

My [findings](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:29587) so far seem to suggest that I need to do an ajax request to get the link but that did not work either.

```
var videoLink = "https://vimeo.com/114166139";

jQuery.get(videoLink, function(data) {
    jQuery(data).filter('meta[name=og:title]').attr("content");
    jQuery(".output").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed due to CORS.

More info about CORS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: There must be a way around it?

Comment: Well, maybe you could use a proxy server for this? But shouldn't the URL be "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/114166139" instead of "https://vimeo.com/114166139" if you are using the Vimeo API?

Comment: I'm not using the Vimeo api. I am just trying to find a general way to get meta info from any site link